# How to change Eclipse Helios with Eclipse Kepler-SR1

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler, helios

I'm using Eclipse SDK version 3.6.2 Helios and want to change to Kepler SR1 for the sake of Installing IBM Worklight. I'm trying to do it with out removing Helios? Is it possible? Earlier I done when I changed from Galileo to Helios by using option 'Install New Software' under 'Help' menu in Eclipse and with some minor tweaks (like changing version number and all). I tried the same with using http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler and It's showing the available software's. But I guess all is from latest version of Kepler. I need Kepler SR1 only as IBM suggests. Or can I keep two separate Eclipse installations? Anybody have suggestions for helping me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's hardly a programming question, and you don't even specify your OS. But yes, you can have different versions of Eclipse side by side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I keep two separate Eclipse installations? Anybody have suggestions for helping me with this?

This is the recommended approach, and even keep two separate Eclipse workspaces.
That means you have to import again your projects, but that allows you to easily go back to your previous Eclipse if the new one has any issue.

You can [download a new Eclipse](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/), and unzip it wherever you want: there is no setup, just an archive to uncompress.